# "Migrations" exceeded the block limit

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle-migration, solidity-0.5.x

I didn't have any problem using solc 0.5.0 (geth 1.9.3), but facing this problem after upgraded to 0.5.12 (geth 1.9.9).

After doing some research, I believe it is because of the changes to the transfer() function in solidity. But unfortunately I didn't get any error message when compiling.

So, I a very confused now, and didn't know if there is any where else I had made error.

Anyone know why solc is not complaining about error / obsolete functions()

Comment: Are you deploying to a private blockchain? Are constantinople/petersburg opcodes eanbled? Since solc 0.5.x by default it will use the new opcodes causing a revert operation if they are not enabled.

Comment: Bingo, this exactly solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is possibly due to the fact that Ethereum has a contract code-size limit of 24KB.

If you contract's code-size exceeds this limit, then no matter what you do - whether it's in your contract code or in your deployment code - the contract deployment will fail.

How to check your contract's code-size:

1. If you're compiling via solc executable, then make sure that the size of the output `bin` file does not exceed 48KB
2. If you're compiling via solc.js (for example, via Truffle), then make sure that the size of the `bytecode` field in the output `json` file does not exceed 48KB

Why 48KB?

> 2 hexdecimal characters = 2 bytes in the text file = 1 byte in the actual bytecode.

Comment: I have multiple contracts within truffle, the largest is only 13KB, but if adding all other contracts together (all the bytecode in all json files) is certainly > 24KB. Will that be an issue?

Comment: @sk: No, that shouldn't be an issue. But you appear to be doing some transaction (executing contract deployment or contract function), which requires more gas than the current block-limit. You might be able to fix it in your `truffle-config.js` file. Alternatively, share your code if you want others to be able to analyze the problem.